# How to make a Java program quit when "Q" is inputted, issue is the default input variable is double

Tags: java

How do I make it so my program is exited when "Q" is inputted? 
I am currently in the process of coding a currency converter from USD to Euros in school, and have been stuck on this part for ages. The issue is that all of my keyboard input variables are double type, resulting in an error whenever "Q" or something alike is inputted. So far, my classes look like this.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CurrencyConverter 
{

    double exchRate;
    double euro;

    public CurrencyConverter(double exchRate){
        this.exchRate = exchRate;
    }

    public double USDToEuro(double usd) {
        double euro = 0;
        euro = usd * exchRate;
        return euro;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Converter
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the value of USD in Euros.");
    double exchRate = kbReader.nextDouble();
    CurrencyConverter ER = new CurrencyConverter(exchRate);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value of USD to be converted.");
        double usd = kbReader.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Your converted value is € " + ER.USDToEuro(usd)+ ".");
    }
    while(1 == 1);
}
}
```

The converter itself works fine, but again, the part that I am stuck on is making it so when "Q" is inputted, it stops the program. How would I perhaps make it so when "Q" is inputted it stops the program WITHOUT an error?

Answer (score 3):

Two simple options:

- you catch that exception and define "anything that isn't a number is meant to end the program"
- instead of calling nextDouble() you retrieve the user input as string

When you have a string, you can compare it against other strings, before trying to turn it into a double value!

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
...
String input = kbReader.readLine().trim();
if( input.equals("Q")){
   //quit
   System.exit(0);
}
// otherwise continue converting
Double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
...
```

In this way you are accepting a more general input, of type string, which you can use for two purposes: leave the program in case of `Q` is inputted; continue converting in case a number is inputted.

Comment: It's dangerous to exit the application by calling `System.exit()`. For example, it will bypass any finally clauses. And if you're running it inside an application server, it will exit the application server. Better to exit by returning from main.

Answer (score 1):

Read the input as a String.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Converter
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = "";
        System.out.println("Please enter the value of USD in Euros.");
        double exchRate = kbReader.nextDouble();
        CurrencyConverter ER = new CurrencyConverter(exchRate);
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a value of USD to be converted.");
            input = kbReader.nextLine();
            try {
                double usd = Double.parseDouble(input);
                System.out.println("Your converted value is € " + ER.USDToEuro(usd)+ ".");
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("That isn't a valid number.");
            }
        }
        while(!input.equals("Q"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the

```
 if ( input = "Q" || input = "q"){
  .....  

  System.exit(0);
```

this way allows you to just accept either the Q as a caps or not. I know when being taught this my teachers preferred the code to be this way. or you could try

```
if ( input.toUpperCase() = "Q") {

...
```

Comment: `input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")` will do the same.

Comment: input.toLowerCase will as well cause java be like that